# Metro Flyouts with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to use the Flyouts from MahApps.Metro in my application. So I added this part to my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <controls:FlyoutsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Flyouts}">
        <controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SettingsViewModel}">
                <view:SettingsFlyout/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:FlyoutsControl>
</controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
```

The `ItemTemplate` will contain the mappings from my viewmodels to the views. `Flyouts` is an `ObservableCollection<IFlyoutViewModel>` and currently only contains my `SettingsViewModel`.

The `IFlyoutViewModel` definition:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyApplication.ViewModel
{
    internal interface IFlyoutViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        bool Visible { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And how I use the `Visible`-property:

```
<controls:Flyout x:Class="MyApplication.View.SettingsFlyout"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                 Header="Settings"
                 Position="Right"
                 IsOpen="{Binding Visible}"
                 Width="300">
    ...
</controls:Flyout>
```

So now I set the `Visible`-property of my SettingsViewModel, but the Flyout won't open. What am I doing wrong?

---

I just tried to assign `IsOpen="true"` hardcoded but this didn't work, too. So displaying the flyout with a datatemplate seems to be the problem...

Comment: try adding this `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay` to IsOpen Property

Comment: if I'm not mistaken this is default, but I'll try

Comment: Can you show the definition of `IFlyoutViewModel` ?

Comment: i extended the question

Comment: May help this https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/999

Comment: kinda complicated, but I'll try it out, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built it like described in the issue dicussion linked by Eldho, now it works. The key ist to define `ItemContainerStyle` and bind `IsOpen` there!

The new `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <controls:FlyoutsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Flyouts}">
        <controls:FlyoutsControl.Resources>
            <view:FlyoutPositionConverter x:Key="FlyoutPositionConverter"/>
        </controls:FlyoutsControl.Resources>
        <controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SettingsViewModel}">
                <view:SettingsFlyout/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:Flyout}}"
               TargetType="{x:Type controls:Flyout}">
                <Setter Property="Header"
                    Value="{Binding Header}" />
                <Setter Property="IsOpen"
                    Value="{Binding Visible}" />
                <Setter Property="Position"
                    Value="{Binding Position, Converter={StaticResource FlyoutPositionConverter}}" />
                <Setter Property="IsModal"
                    Value="{Binding IsModal}" />
                <Setter Property="Theme" Value="Accent" />
            </Style>
        </controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </controls:FlyoutsControl>
</controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
```

The new `IFlyoutViewModel`:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyApplication.ViewModel
{
    internal interface IFlyoutViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string Header { get; }
        bool Visible { get; set; }
        Position Position { get; set; }
        bool IsModal { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Position
    {
        Top,
        Left,
        Right,
        Bottom
    }
}
```

The `FlyoutPositionConverter` is just a mapper between my position enum and the `MahApps.Metro.Controls.Position` because I didn't want to use the real positon in my viewmodel interface.

Also the view now no longer needs to be a `Flyout`, it can be a normal usercontrol.

Comment: Hi Florian, do you assume there is only 1 single UserControl to display for all ViewModels as Flyout? "<view:SettingsFlyout/>". How could I specify for each Flyout a different UserControl with MVVM. Thanks

Comment: @Bill no, you can have multiple flyouts - the viewmodels are stored in the Property `Flyouts` and you can specify multiple DataTemplates for the different views. In this case you have to use a ItemTemplateChooser, though.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not getting how I can change the UserControl with each Flyout? As you said, Flyout property has ViewModels not actual Views, how am I going to change the View? Maybe I am missing something in here.

Comment: @Bill In my case, the view is specified by the ItemTemplate. If you want to be able to have different templates - meaning different views - you have to use a TemplateChooser. You can google this, it's a common approach

Comment: @Bill the idea of the TemplateChooser here is to take a different DataTemplate depending on the type of the item - in this case your viewmodel - that is being shown

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution also should work well if you call OnPropertyChanged on the Setter of your Visible-Property

Comment: I do call PropertyChanged when setting my visible property

Comment: and is your binding set to TwoWay at the same time? I use the flyout in a mvvm environment just like you described at the beginning....I just set IsOpen={Binding IsMenuOpen, Mode=TwoWay} and set the value in my viewModel

Comment: yeah, I manually set it because Eldho suggested it in a comment, but it didn't work - not really surprising, since twoway is default for normal properties