# How to bind to Metro Flyout ItemContainerStyle property from button in RightWindowCommands?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mahapps.metro, flyout

I'm working off the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130858/metro-flyouts-with-mvvm) as a basis for my current attempt to manage the opening and closing of a Metro flyout.  The difference is that I have a `ToggleButton` defined in the `RightWindowCommands`.  The desired behavior is that the `IsChecked`status of this button should be bound to the IsOpen property of the underlying flyout viewmodel.

This is the XAML with some of my failed attempts:

```
<controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <controls:FlyoutsControl x:Name="FlyoutsControl" >
        <controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:Flyout}}" TargetType="{x:Type controls:Flyout}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
                <Setter Property="IsOpen"  Value="{Binding IsOpen}" />
                <Setter Property="Position" Value="{Binding Position}" />
                <Setter Property="Theme" Value="Accent" />
            </Style>
        </controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SettingsFlyoutViewModel}">
                <local:SettingsFlyoutView x:Name="SettingsFlyoutView"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:FlyoutsControl>
</controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
<controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <controls:WindowCommands>
<!--<ToggleButton Content="{iconPacks:FontAwesome Kind=FighterJetSolid}" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" ToolTip="Toggle flyout." BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=SettingsFlyoutView, Path=IsOpen}" Cursor="Hand"/>-->
        <!--<ToggleButton Content="{iconPacks:FontAwesome Kind=FighterJetSolid}" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" ToolTip="Toggle flyout." BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:MetroWindow}}, Path=IsOpen}"/>-->
        <!--<ToggleButton Content="{iconPacks:FontAwesome Kind=FighterJetSolid}" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" ToolTip="Toggle flyout." BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=FlyoutsControl, Path=DataContext.IsOpen}"/>-->
        <!--<ToggleButton Content="{iconPacks:FontAwesome Kind=FighterJetSolid}" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" ToolTip="Toggle flyout." BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type controls:Flyout}}, Path=IsOpen}"/>-->
    </controls:WindowCommands>
</controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

What is the right binding strategy to bind IsChecked to IsOpen?

Comment: How do you identify the "underlying" Flyout for a specific button?

Comment: @mm8 Good point - I edited my question to include the previously omitted ItemTemplate.  Here SettingsFlyoutView is a user control which leverages SettingsFlyoutViewModel as the backing viewmodel.  I'm still having difficulty doing the binding tho; see the newest attempt at top of the commented section.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
    <Controls:FlyoutsControl>
        <Controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Controls:Flyout}}" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:Flyout}">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
                <Setter Property="IsOpen"  Value="{Binding IsOpen}" />
                <Setter Property="Position" Value="{Binding Position}" />
                <Setter Property="Theme" Value="Accent" />
            </Style>
        </Controls:FlyoutsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Controls:Flyout x:Name="yourMahAppFlyout" Header="Flyout" Position="Right" Width="200">
            <!-- Your custom content here -->
        </Controls:Flyout>
    </Controls:FlyoutsControl>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <ToggleButton Content="{iconPacks:FontAwesome Kind=FighterJetSolid}" Background="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" ToolTip="Toggle flyout." BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" 
                  IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=yourMahAppFlyout, Path=IsOpen}" Cursor="Hand"/>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
```

Comment: When I add the `<Controls:Flyout>` line item, I get a runtime exception `Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.`  One difference between my scenario and the Mahapps website snippet is that their example doesn't use an ItemContainerStyle, which I believe I need for binding to my viewmodel properties based on the link at top.  Any thoughts how to resolve the exception?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Can you post your code sample to look at it?

Comment: I have placed a copy of the project as it throws the exception here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AsvM6Pyke4A6hCRyovosrs0kIKGG, The content above can be found in MainWindow.xaml.